# why are listed generic functions has overwrite itself on typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, generics

I am trying to do some operations using **IOperation** interface. but i have strange error.
When i log operation values or operation result, there is no problem but when i try to log interface itself, i get overwrited operation values and result.

my code is here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-flpdu1?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts

```
//app/app.component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IOperation } from './definitions/operation';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  operations: {
    [operationName: string]: IOperation
  }[] = [];

  columns: {
    columnName: string,
    columnOperations: IOperation[]
  }[] = [];

  constructor() {
    let sum: IOperation = {
      operationName: "sum",
      operationFunction: this.sumFunction
    };
    let avg: IOperation = {
      operationName: "avg",
      operationFunction: this.avgFunction
    };
    this.operations["sum"] = sum;
    this.operations["avg"] = avg;
    this.columns = [
      {
        columnName: "column1",
        columnOperations: [this.operations["sum"]]
      },
      {
        columnName: "column2",
        columnOperations: [this.operations["avg"]]
      },
      {
        columnName: "column3",
        columnOperations: []
      },
      {
        columnName: "column4",
        columnOperations: [this.operations["sum"], this.operations["avg"]]
      },
      {
        columnName: "column5",
        columnOperations: []
      }
    ];
    this.doOperation();
  }
  sumFunction(values: number[]): number {
    let result: number = 0;
    values.forEach((i: number) => {
      result += i;
    });
    return result;
  }
  avgFunction(values: number[]): number {
    let result: number = 0;
    values.forEach((i: number) => {
      result += i;
    });
    return result / values.length;
  }
  doOperation(): void {
    let values: number[][] = [
      [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
      [6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
      [11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
      [16, 17, 18, 19, 10],
      [21, 22, 23, 24, 25],
      [26, 27, 28, 29, 20],
      [31, 32, 33, 34, 35]
    ];
    for (let i = 0; i &#60; this.columns.length; i++) {
      for (let k = 0; k &#60; this.columns[i].columnOperations.length; k++) {
        console.log(i+","+k);

        let gc: number[] = [];
        let gcOperation:IOperation=this.columns[i].columnOperations[k];

        for (let j = 0; j &#60; values.length; j++) { gc.push(values[j][i]); }

        gcOperation.operationValues = gc;

        gcOperation.operationResult = gcOperation.operationFunction(gcOperation.operationValues);
        console.log("correct answer:"+gcOperation.operationResult);//correct answer
        console.log(gcOperation);
        //gcOperation.operationResult is wrong here
      }
    }
  }
}

// /definitions/operation.ts
export interface IOperation {
  operationName: string,
  operationFunction?: Function,
  operationValues?: any[],
  operationResult?: any
}
```

as you can see in console i log **operation.operationResult** and it is correct. then i immediately log same "operation" and it has wrong **operationResult**.

i am using `opera 54.0` and `chrome 68.0`. 
if you don't have same problem (if it's only for my computer somehow)

[there is what i see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlDTZ.png)

(sorry if i brake any rules of site it's my first question and my English is not really good. thanks everyone want to help me).

Comment: Tested on chrome 68 on macOS. no problem in the log

Comment: Please add the relevant parts of the code directly to the question, do not link to external resources. External links tend to get broken which makes the question useless for future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of operationResult probably changes during code execution. At some point it is 112 - and at some later point it is 133.

Since you are **logging** a **object reference** (not a deep copy), when logging objects to the console, this strange behaviour can easily occur.
While the object representation at the top is a **snapshot** of the moment you logged, the values after "opening" the object are the **current** values instead.

You might want to log a deep copy of your object in order to verify my assumption (for example by using corresponding functions of lodash/jquery)

Comment: thank you man. i am using let newObject=Object.assing({},oldObject);
deep copy is my hero.
(
//last section
...
let gc: number[] = [];
let gcOperation:IOperation=Object.assign({},this.columns[i].columnOperations[k]);

for (let j = 0; j < values.length; j++) { gc.push(values[j][i]); }
...
)